# Rails - Add custom headers to response based on API version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, http-headers, rack

What I am trying to do is pretty simple. There are multiple versions of a Rails REST API. So, there are routes like:

```
http://www.example.com/v1/user.json
http://www.example.com/v2/user.json
http://www.example.com/v3/user.json
```

What I want to do is add custom http headers to the response based on the API version endpoint that is requested.

In my config/application.rb file, I tried:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!('my_header_1' => 'my_value_1', 'my_header_2' => 'my_value_2')
```

I have also tried this in my config/routes.rb file:

```
scope path: "v1", controller: :test do
    get "action_1" => :action_1
    get "action_2" => :action_2
    Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!('my_header_1' => 'my_value_1', 'my_header_2' => 'my_value_2')
end
```

But both of these snippets append custom headers to the response irrespective of the API version endpoint.

I think I can write a middleware that checks the request url and appends the response headers based on that but it sounds a bit hackish.

Is there a better way to achieve this? Preferably via config or some central piece of code?

Answer (score 10):

What about using a `before_action` on your controllers? I imagine each API version has its own controllers? That way you could do something like:

```
class API::V1::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_headers

  protected

  def set_headers
    response.headers['X-Foo'] = 'V1'
  end
end
```

Comment: In case `before_action` doesn't work, try `prepend_before_action`.